# I want to hide the "Manage questions" button from question creation form of Drupal Quiz

Tags: quiz

I am using drupal [quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module. It is working fine. My issue is I want to hide the "Manage questions" button from question creation form.

Any help would be appreciable.